# Como rodar meu App em multiplas plataformas

Tags: android, mobile

Boa tarde,

Alguém tem experiência em App para rodar em múltiplas plataformas. Eu estou desenvolvendo um App, porém, estou fazendo ele para Android, como eu faço para ele roda também em IOs, WindowsPhone e etc... Igual funciona o Whattsapp.

Comment: Procure no Google por Cordova e para layout o IONIC

Comment: Rodrigo dependendo da aplicação você pode criar a WebView, utilizando um framework tpo Jquery mobile, no caso da apple ela não aceita um app somente em webview onde você poderia utilizar ele também no Safari. Ou seja você utiliza o webview na sua parte principal com adaptações utilizando botões, chamadas do ws tudo no swift. É massa usar o xamarim? É, mas no mercado de trabalho não é ele que funciona e vai por mim, sugeri o uso do xamarim na empresa para fazer o mesmo que você disse, deram risada.

Answer (score 5):

Existem 2 "tipos" de aplicativos, os **Nativos** e os **Híbridos**.

**Nativos** :

Apps nativos tem linguagens e frameworks padrões, por exemplo, no caso do Android se usa **Java**(ou **Kotlin**), **XML** e normalmente tudo é feito no IDE **Android Studio**.

Já no caso do **IOS** as linguagens usadas são o **Swift** e o **Obective-c** tudo feito no **X-Code**. Além disso nesse caso é necessário ter um computador rodando um sistema operacional **MAC OS**

As vantagens de se programar nativamente são muitas:

- Melhor UX (Experiência do Usuário). Já que tudo é do jeito com que o usuário está acostumado usar no seu aparelho
- Comunidade ativa. Se você perceber a maioria das duvidas que não tem respostas aqui costumam ser de plataformas Híbridas, graças ao fato de sua comunidade não ser tão grande e ativa
- Previsibilidade dos resultados. É muito mais fácil prever um código escrito especificamente para aquele sistema. Em um Híbrido você dificilmente saberá como será o resultado em todo e qualquer aparelho.

**Híbridos :**

Hoje em dia existem diversas formas de se programar aplicativos Híbridos (que rodam nas duas plataformas).

**Ex.** Ionic, Cordova, Xamarin...

Cada uma delas tem sua própria maneira de se escrever e estruturar o código. Esse tipo de app pode ser usado como alternativa aos Nativos e servem exatamente para que o mesmo aplicativo rode na maioria das plataformas. Porém existem todos os pontos negativos antes citados.

**Respondendo a pergunta :**

Não é possivel. Não existem ferramentas para se converter um app nativamente **Android** em **IOS** ou **Windows Phone**, o que você pode fazer é recorrer para umas das opções citadas acima. No caso do **WhatsApp**, para cada plataforma ele tem um App **Nativo** que tem seus códigos completamente diferentes

Comment: Digamos que eu queira fazer uma grande aplicação, estilo uma rede social... seria melhor eu fazer Nativa ou Hibrida? Sabendo que se de certo corre chances de contratação de pessoas para me ajudar e etc. Seria melhor eu fazer a coisa acontece hibrida sabendo que depois teria que mudar tudo ou melhor meter a cara e fazer tudo nativa.

Comment: Na minha optinião a melhor opção é sempre nativa, principalmente uma rede social que depende da base de usuários. Os híbridos muitas vezes tem a navegação lenta e geralmente o UX n fica ideal. Melhor perder um pouco de tempo a mais no começo do que ter muito re-trabalho dps

Comment: Apenas corrigindo, Xamarin não é híbrido. Você desenvolve em C, mas ele gera aplicações nativas.

Answer (score 1):

também desenvolvo android. estou seguindo o caminho do Xamarim, procure Xamarim forms, microsoft, programando em c# multiplataforma com desempenho idêntico ao desenvolvimento nativo. ótima sintaxe com c#, super bem apoiado pela Microsoft e passou a ser gratuito esse ano, pois a Xamarin foi comprada pela Microsoft e a disponibilizou de gratuitamente, ótima ferramenta para usar junto com o VisualStudio, Ai poderá portar grande parte do seu codigo criando pequenas alterações apenas na parte visual específica de cada plataforma, usando seus componentes nativos. achei a melhor opção. qualidade vs desempenho, confira.

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo, vou pensar no caso. Vlw mesmo.